# Detecting specific exceptions Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

To begin with I wanted to catch the abort 403 error which I thought would throw an AccessDeniedHttpException so I tried to catch the error like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

use Event;

use App\Events\UserNotAllowed;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */    
        protected $dontReport = [
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        AccessDeniedHttpException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException) {
            Event::fire(new UserNotAllowed($request));
            return redirect()->to("/home");
        }
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work because only 404 errors are given the right class whilst all others are given a general exception which you should be able to catch the number from like this.

```
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // Or === 
        if ($e->getStatusCode() == 403) {
            Event::fire(new UserNotAllowed($request));
            return redirect()->to("/home");
        }
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

But when doing this all other error pages fail to work giving a general 500 error in my webrowser
Is there an easy way to listen or simply catch the errors without changing the whole src abort function from Laravel?

Comment: Is there a specific need for that?

Comment: Well I would like to know when a user tries to access a page they are not allowed to go to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the report method in the Exception Handler, as per the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#report-method):

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
      echo $e->getStatusCode();
    }  
    return parent::report($e);
}
```

Comment: Nope, it works, but you should define the error type in the abort. use abort(404). I have updated the answer to suit your needs.

Comment: abort() needs one argument, so abort() only will throw another exception.

Comment: Yes... it would be possible to do it like this but im not talking about page not found (404) but the access denied (403). so... when somone tries to access a page that does not exist that it would not fill up with useless logs of people making spelling mistakes.

Comment: I am not sure, what are you trying to achieve, but whatever the exception type it will work. You just need to know the exception type. For 403 the type is HttpException.

Comment: Also you can check by statusCode, I will update the answer to show that.

Comment: Yes  ` public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
            if ($e->getStatusCode() == 403) {
                dd($e);
            }
        }

        return parent::report($e);
    } ` Seems to be the best "solution" Thank you man update your awnser to that and ill accept it.